# create a snapshot to a EBS volume with tags

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-java-sdk

I want to create a snapshot for a EBS volume with tags as "backup. "I've written a method to create a snapshot to a EBS volume. The snapshot is being created correctly. However the snapshot is wihout having any tag. The method is as follows.

```
public Snapshot createEbsSnapshot(String volumeId)
        throws IOException {

    logger.log("============Creating snapshot for a volume: " + volumeId +" ==============");

    String description = "This is a snapshot created by using AWS-Java SDK";

    CreateSnapshotRequest snapshotRequest = new CreateSnapshotRequest(
            volumeId, description);

    CreateSnapshotResult snapshotResult = ec2Client
            .createSnapshot(snapshotRequest);

    Snapshot snapshot = snapshotResult.getSnapshot();       

    logger.log("============Snapshot creation for a volume: " + volumeId +" is done.==============");

    return snapshot;
}
```

I'm not sure whether we can do this by using aws-java sdk. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AmazonEC2Client class has a [createTags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html#createTags(com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.CreateTagsRequest)) method that can assign tags to a resource.
If you take the [SnapshotId of the CreateSnapshotResult](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/Snapshot.html#getSnapshotId()) and use that to call the createTags method, I think you should be able to assign a tag to the snapshot.

Comment: createTags method of a AmazonEC2Client did the trick. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

I might be late to the party, but instead of using java you can use python which can solve your purpose in few lines of code and in a better way.
I found a better Lambda script which takes snapshot of EBS volume(Secondary volume) based on ec2 instance tags.

For example, if your ec2 instance have tag "Backup:true". Snapshot of all the secondary volumes will be taken and snapshot will be given the name of instance.

Blog Post - https://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2018/05/automated-ebs-volume-snapshot-lambda.html

Demo - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9E9F8HD_7E

Hope this helps!

Comment: quite useful. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

You have to take the snapshot ID returned from the call to `createSnapshot()` and then use that ID in another API call to create tags on the snapshot.

Comment: Thanks for answer. createSnapshot() just creates a snapshot. If possible can you please provide me code snippet for second API call.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to create the parameter with all the tags in it.
More details on 
For example:

```
let snapshotParams = {
    DryRun : false,
    VolumeId : vol-123abc, //ID of the volume
    TagSpecifications: [{
        ResourceType: 'snapshot',
        Tags: [
            {
              Key: 'ServerName',
              Value: 'Server123'
            },                {
              Key: 'Department',
              Value: 'Accounting'
            }
        ]//this can be obtained by the instance object
    }]
}
ec2.createSnapshot(snapshotParams,(err,data)=>{
    if(err){
       console.log(err, err.stack)
    } else {
       console.log(data)
    }
}
```

You can create a function and iterate through your ec2 instances object to obtain the Tags.